# What does this vim cmd mean? :%y+

Tags: unix, vim, administrator, gvim, vi

I found a command to select all text in Vi/Vim file.

```
:%y+
```

Could someone explain the line, please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### What does this vim cmd mean?

```
:%y+
```

- `:` switches into Command-Line mode
- `%` has a special meaning—it stands for all the lines in the
  current file
- `y` yank command (copy operation)
- `+` the clipboard

So

`:%y+` means switch into command line mode, select all the text, copy it, and place the copy on the clipboard

---

#### Further reading

- [Practical Vim: Edit Text at the Speed of Thought (Pragmatic Programmers)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1934356980)

[image]